# Is it possible to create a macro to hide/show rows 5 to 28, assigned to a button that will translate to iOS/android?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a spreadsheet to help calculate drug doses in pediatrics. My hospital would like to make it look like more of a form: Input weight + age, click "go" and the doses appear below in the table. The idea is anyone can download the file from the trust when they need it, to a computer or more likely; their mobile phone.

So far I've been able to create a macro and assign it to the button to achieve this on a computer, however it doesn't translate to iOS or Android.

Is there a way around this?

Would it be simpler to create a hyperlink to another sheet showing the table of doses?

Comment: I'd make it a [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).  Maybe make it look like a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting looking age/weight dosage calculator from [Medscape.com](https://reference.medscape.com/calculator/iron-replacement-parenteral-dosing)

[image]